# Why Python getcontext().prec = 4 sometimes gives 3 decimals instead of 4?

Tags: python, decimal, precision

I am new to python, and in my new trip I have encountered this using the `decimal` module:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 4; print(Decimal(7)/Decimal(9));
0.7778 # everything ok
>>>
>>> getcontext().prec = 4; print(Decimal(2).sqrt());
1.414 # why 3 and not 4?
>>>
>>> getcontext().prec = 10;    
>>> print(Decimal(10).log10()/Decimal(2).log10()); 
3.321928094 # why 9 if precision is set to 10?
```

Looking from the https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html I didn't find a mention on that.

Why does it happen?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: At a guess: it's the number of *significant* digits: there is also a digit in front of the decimal point for the second and third example (the 0 in the first example is not significant).

Comment: It seems to not, please check my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that edit.

Comment: Sorry, man, you were right! I didn't make the edit cause when I started to type I stopped and rechecked if you were right, and you are right! :) I am gonna delete my upper comment what do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a guess: it's the number of significant digits: there is also a digit in front of the decimal point for the second and third example (the 0 in the first example is not significant).

Note that the fourth bullet in the documentation says:

> The decimal module incorporates a notion of significant places so that
>   1.30 + 1.20 is 2.50.

Compare (using your first example, but with a larger number):

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 8
>>> print Decimal(7000)/Decimal(9)
777.77778
>>> getcontext().prec = 4
>>> print Decimal(7000)/Decimal(9)
777.8
>>> getcontext().prec = 2
>>> print Decimal(7000)/Decimal(9)
7.8E+2
```

Unfortunately, most examples in the documentation are restricted to numbers of order 1, so this doesn't show clearly.