# Is there any way to do computations with fixed number of digits after decimal point?

Tags: python, decimal

For some application I need to my computations using 3 digits of precision after decimal. I found the following method:

```
getcontext().prec = 100

THREE_PLACES = Decimal('0.001')

x = Decimal('2.41').quantize(THREE_PLACES)

y = (x * x).quantize(THREE_PLACES)
```

but This makes the code very ugly because I need to write quantize(THREE_PLACES) for all my operations which are actually a lot. And also the numbers I am getting with may be very big so that getcontext().prec = 100 may not work for all of them. Any better alternates to this one ? I also found the solution using f string's but that makes the code even uglier.

Edit: I have to explain that getcontext().prec sets the number of significat digits not digits after decimal and because I may have big enough numbers I set it to a big number. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094459/why-python-getcontext-prec-4-sometimes-gives-3-decimals-instead-of-4).

Comment: If you want computations done with three places of precision why are you using 100 places of precision then rounding to three places?

Comment: @DarrylG as far as I know getocontext().prec sets the number of significant digits not the number of digits after decimal point

Comment: @MisterMiyagi see the edit.

Comment: When you say "some application I need to my computations using 3 digits of precision after decimal" are you referring to display precision or computation precision?  quantize is rounding the number after computation (i.e you're computing to 100 decimal places then rounding).  You mention f-strings, but that's also just rounding for display when you provide a format specifier.

Comment: I would suggest doing all arithmetic with integers, and only when you need to output, divide by 1000.

Comment: @DarrylG I am currently quantizing after all the operations :) and the code is quite ugly I need it for computations for sure using f string's is more ugly because I have to convert to Decimal then.

Comment: @trincot I think that works only for addition and subtraction when multiplying it becomes more complex

Comment: For multiplication of `a` and `b` you need to just divide again (integer division) by 1000. `c=a*b//1000`. And output as `c/1000`

Comment: @trincot Thanks! :) got it. It may be a bit ugly but I can create a class to do this kind of operations.

Comment: Why doesn't `getcontext().prec = 3; x = Decimal('2.41'); y = x*x; print(y);` work for your example?

Comment: @DarrylG you can try it only gives two digits after decimal :) and if the number is big enough for example y = x * x * x * x * x * x * x * x  it won't give any digits after decimal (1138) because there will be four significant digits before decimal leaving no place for digits after decimal. Simply getcontext().prec will set the number of significat digits before and after decimal not only after decimal

Comment: @TahaAkbari--right, but if you try using the scale idea using integers you will see that you get three decimals places, but they are all incorrect i.e.  you get 2742.363 but the actual answer should be 2742.542.

Comment: @DarrylG I see but I can probably do something like (a * b +500) // 1000 to do multipilication I think It should be the same way Decimal's act.

Comment: @TahaAkbari---we should start with your goal.  Are you trying to simulate computations that will be running on a fixed-point processor?  Also, (a * b +500) // 1000, I asume is rounding.  But, this still gives the incorrect answer to three decimal places.

Comment: @DarrylG yes I am trying to simulate computatinos that will be running on a fixed-point processor. I am taking a numberical methods in computations class in university and they sayed that if you do your intermediate computations with four digits it will be fine with three digits I think they are wrong but I have to complete my assignment using this assumption :) so I am going to simulate fixed-point processor but with one more digit accuracy I need and will remove the last digit in the final answer.

Comment: @TahaAkbari--since this is a class rather than for work simulate accuracy is not crucial.  So in that case carry on.